# Add email address to Outlook email message if the value of a cell is = 1

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to get some help with sending an email message to anyone with a "1" in column E.  I have a worksheet with a range of employees and their phone numbers.  Following their phone numbers is a list of events they want to be notified for. If I place a 1 in one of the columns after their name I would like their email address added to the email.

The column headers would be something like A=Last Name, B=First name, C=Phone Number, D=Email Address, E=Event 1, F=Event 2, G=event 3 and so on.

I was able to get the email code to pull all email addresses from a set range but I can't figure out how to add the if command to look for a set value in one of the event columns (E, F, G...).  It would need to loop through the entire range and then pull address only for those selected individuals who had the set value in one of the event columns.

Here is my code so far:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
Dim strsub As String, strbody As String
Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
Dim sTo As String

Set emailRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:D500")

For Each cl In emailRng
    sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
Next

sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


strto = sTo

strcc = ""
strbcc = ""
strsub = "'NOTIFICATION'  - " & "Notification"
strbody = "<img src=Z:\Logo2.jpg width=624 height=74>" & _
          "<font size=2 font face=Verdana color=black>" & "<br>" & _
          "The following notification was received:</B><br><br>" & _
          "COPY AND PAST NOTIFICATION RECEIVED HERE" & "<br><br>" & _
          "<b>Control Center</b><br><br>"


With OutMail
    '.SentOnBehalfOfName = ""
    .to = strto
    .cc = strcc
    .bcc = strbcc
    .Subject = strsub
    'You can add a file to the mail like this
    .HTMLBody = strbody
    .Display    ' or use .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is this:

```
For Each cl In emailRng
    If cl.Offset(,1) = 1 Then sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
Next
```

Here you are checking if 1 column away from the email address (Event 1 in col E) is checked for notification.

However, since you stated you could have *n* number of events, you will need a way to determine which event you are sending an email for. I don't know how you plan to process that, but you could, for example, call the Sub from another Sub and pass the event number and use that as the offset.

So

```
Sub EmailEvent()

    SendEventEmail 1 'send event 1 email
    SendEventEmail 2 'send event 2 email
    SendEventEmail 3 'send event 3 email

End Sub
```

Then in your sub that actually sends the mail it would say

```
Sub SendEventEmail(n as Long)
Rem n is the Event Number

Rem Your Code ... 

For Each cl in emailRng
     If cl.Offset(,n) = 1 Then sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
Next

Rem Rest of code ... 

End Sub
```